# How do I convert negative time value into 24 hour time in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, time

I have a column in a table of type TIME. I want to get a result that applies a time shift that results in a 24 hour clock representation of that shift. To add the shift, my query contains...

```
select addtime(boo,'01:00:00') as yada
```

But any value that gets taken out of the 24 hour range ends up outside the 24 hour range, such as...

**23:45 ends up as 24:45 (when I want 00:45:00)**

If I go the other way and subtract the hour from a value less than 1am, I get...

**00:15 ends up as -00:45:00 when I want (23:15:00)**

Now, I understand that the TIME format in MYSQL is "duration" and not the actual "time", but for the life of me I can't figure out how to convert to an actual clock time as outlined above. Please help me or kill me. Either will end my suffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is just add your `boo` TIME value to any date (e.g. today) then add your time delta and after that just return time part with `TIME()`

```
SELECT TIME(CURDATE() 
             + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC('23:45:00') SECOND 
             + INTERVAL 1 HOUR) new_time
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| new_time |
+----------+
| 00:45:00 |
+----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/20034)** demo

Comment: This works perfectly for my needs. And I find that I can also use second interval which is the format of my timeshift, so I can use:
`SELECT TIME(CURDATE() 
             + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(Boo) SECOND 
             - INTERVAL 3600 SECOND) new_time FROM TABLE`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to just use a `DATETIME` data type instead, then ignore the date part.  If you're not dealing with huge amounts of data, or searching by the actual times I can't see an issue.

As a bonus you'll be able to manipulate the data with the likes of `+ INTERVAL 1 HOUR` etc.

When extracting it just use `TIME(boo)`

As you know, the MySQL `TIME` type is not restricted to 24 hour time so this is probably the closest you'll get... I'm sure you could construct a query using `MOD()` etc but it's probably not worth it.